# Unable to get squid working for remote users

Tags: squid, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to setup squid 3.2.4, but I have not been able to get it working for remote users.  Works fine locally.  Unable to figure out what I am doing wrong...

```
http_port 3128 transparent ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB cert=/usr/share/ssl-cert/myCA.pem

refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320

acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8     # RFC 1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC 1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC 1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src fc00::/7       # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10      # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access allow localhost
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow all

cache deny all

via off
forwarded_for off

header_access From deny all
header_access Server deny all
header_access WWW-Authenticate deny all
header_access Link deny all
header_access Cache-Control deny all
header_access Proxy-Connection deny all
header_access X-Cache deny all
header_access X-Cache-Lookup deny all
header_access Via deny all
header_access Forwarded-For deny all
header_access X-Forwarded-For deny all
header_access Pragma deny all
header_access Keep-Alive deny all

acl ip1 localip 1.1.1.90
acl ip2 localip 1.1.1.91
acl ip3 localip 1.1.1.92
acl ip4 localip 1.1.1.93
acl ip5 localip 1.1.1.94
tcp_outgoing_address 1.1.1.90 ip1
tcp_outgoing_address 1.1.1.91 ip2
tcp_outgoing_address 1.1.1.92 ip3
tcp_outgoing_address 1.1.1.93 ip4
tcp_outgoing_address 1.1.1.94 ip5
tcp_outgoing_address 1.1.1.90
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you included what troubleshooting steps you have done. Is remote traffic getting to the server? Check [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html). What is squid doing with the remote traffic? Turn on [debug logging](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/debug_options/) with `debug_options ALL,9`.

Comment: figured it out, apparently squid was already installed using apt-get and I was trying to run 3.2 which you have to compile.

Answer (score 0):

does your squid-machine know the route to these "remote users"?

could you clarify what your local net is and what your remote users are? What issue at the remote users? Timeout? Forbidden?